# Standard practise for ajax request page output?

Tags: php, ajax, coding-style

What is the standard practise with PHP pages that are used for Ajax requests? Should they print out a single value (ex: get points of player with id = x)? Does/should a single page serve multiple requests? If so, how can code be grouped on the PHP side?

P.S: An additional question: If a templating system like Smarty is used, would it be more interesting security-wise to call the PHP page being used instead of calling the request page directly?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the security question? What is the difference between the php page being used or the request page directly? In my perception you will always call a smarty page through php right? What am I missing?

Comment: @Arend: Sure. An example. I have some javascript that is calling a page that gives points to users according to how long they've been connected to a site. At the moment, the name of the page is visible in the html source as well as names of POST variables including a user id (possibility of tampering). If I call the underlying PHP page instead (somepage.tpl:javascript->somepage.php) some of the information can be implicit and information can be rerouted to the other page through PHP.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it but only partially. In general you don't have to put user_id's in post variables because you can get this information from sessions. For the rest it usually should not matter that much how much people can see as long as you check the credentials / permissions of the users in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this piece of code in Javascript. Backend wise things are organized in a MVC type of organisation, so things affecting one module are usually grouped together. In general I also create a sperate module for a seperate model, but in some cases you may deviate from this principle.

**PHP**

Execute a piece of code and wrap it inside a try/catch block. This way error messages may be propagated to the frontend. This method helps in that regard to convert exceptions to a readable error. (to debug from json).

```
try {
    //... execute code ..  go about your buisness..
    $this->result = "Moved  " . count($files) . " files ";
    // result can be anything that can be serialized by json_encode()
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $this->error = $e->getMessage() . ' l: '  . $e->getLine() . ' f:' . $e->getFile();
   // return an error message if there is an exception. Also throw exceptions yourself to make your life easier.
}
// json response basically does something like echo json_encode(array("error" => $this->error, "result" => $this->result))
return $this->jsonResponse();
```

For error handling I often use this to parse errors.

```
public function parseException($e) {
    $result = 'Exception: "';
    $result .= $e->getMessage();
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    foreach (range(0, 10) as $i) {
        $result .= '" @ ';
        if (!isset($trace[$i])) {
            break;
        }
        if (isset($trace[$i]['class'])) {
            $result .= $trace[$i]['class'];
            $result .= '->';
        }
        $result .= $trace[$i]['function'];
        $result .= '(); ';
        $result .= $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() . "\n\n";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Javascript side**

```
/**
 * doRequest in an ajax development tool to quickly execute data posts.
 * @requires jQuery.log
 * @param action (string): url for the action to be called. in config.action the prefix for the url can be set
 * @param data (object): data to be send. eg. {'id':5, 'attr':'value'}
 * @param successCallback (function): callback function to be executed when response is success
 * @param errorCallback (function): callback function to be executed when response is success
 */
jQuery.doRequest = function (action, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if (typeof(successCallback) == "undefined") {
        successCallback = function(){};
    } 
    if (typeof(errorCallback) == "undefined") {
        errorCallback = function(data ){
            alert(data.error);
        };
    }
    jQuery.log(action);

    jQuery.post(action, data, function (data, status)
    {

        jQuery.log(data);
        jQuery.log(status);
        if (data.error !== null || status != 'success') {
            // error handler
            errorCallback(data);
        } else {
            successCallback(data);
        }
    },'json');
};
```

Note: the error callbacks are very nice if you combine them with something like [pNotify](http://pines.sourceforge.net/pnotify/)

Answer (score 3):

I think it makes sense to create arrays in php, then convert them to JSON and send back as a JSON object. This allows for more flexible manipulation of data both server and client side.

Comment: After struggling with this question myself, this was the conclusion I came to as well. It makes developing a lot easier too when you *know* you're always expecting json. Some things are just impossible without it.

Comment: I hadn't considered this approach. Do you have JSON objects correspond one to one with PHP objects?

Comment: @James yes, you replicate the same data structures you use as JSON objects in php using arrays.